# Insert text at the beginning of every new line

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm having an issue. I'm making a video transcription solution. When I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I need to add a time flag — so that the user could type until they hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again, but all I get is the time flag at the end of each line.

I appreciate any help.

#### Expected Result

```
[hh:mm:ss] my text
```

#### Actual Result

```
my text [hh:mm:ss]
my new text
```

#### Code

```
//if (!(start_element.hasAttribute('title'))) {
  start_element.setAttributes({
    'title': tim
  });

  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;

  console.log(evt.data.keyCode);

  if (evt.data.keyCode == 13) {
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertHtml('[' + tim + ']');
  }
//}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does not work here on Stack Overflow due to CKEditor using an IFrame which causes a cross-origin policy violation.

You can see a full working demo here on JSFiddle:

> https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/xy96htus/

You essentially need set a very small timeout that gets called after you press enter, before text should be inserted. For this example, I used 100 milliseconds. It works well for me.

I also tried to set the `readonly` for the editor to prevent typing. This does not seem to work. SO you need to trust that someone does not type really-fast after hitting enter. The issue is just that the insertHTML happens too quickly, before the line-feed is entered into the editor.

```js
var $target = $('#modal');
var editorName = 'foobar';

clearEditorInstances();

// Add textarea to target div.
$target.append($('<form>').append($('<textarea>', {
  id: editorName,
  name: editorName
}))).hide();

// Setup editor.
$('textarea#' + editorName).ckeditor({
  height: 300,
  toolbarStartupExpanded: true,
  width: '100%',
  on: {
    instanceReady: function(e) {
      $target.show(); // Show editor, when ready.
      insertTime(this);
    },
    key: function(e) {
      if (e.data.keyCode == 13 /* Enter key */ ) {
        insertTime(this);
      }
    }
  }
});

function insertTime(editor) {
  editor.document.$.body.readonly = true;
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    var timestamp = moment().format('HH:mm:ss');
    var timeHtml = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml('<span>' + timestamp + ' </span>');
    editor.insertElement(timeHtml);
    editor.document.$.body.readonly = false;
  }, 100 /* Typing delay */ );
}

function clearEditorInstances() {
  for (name in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy();
  }
}
```

```css
#modal {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 45px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.7.0/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.7.0/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="modal"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end, you could use regex to move all time flags from the end to the beginning.
Use `/^(.*)(\[[0-9][0-9]?:[[0-9][0-9]?\])$/gm`[(Regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/6OgQL5/2/) to find it, and replace with `$2 $1`. Because it only matches at the end of the line, it shouldn't pick up any in the middle, if someone were to place a manual timestamp.

Explanation (from Regex101)

> /^(.*)([[0-9][0-9]?:[[0-9][0-9]?])$/gm
>
> ^ asserts position at start of a line
>
> 1st Capturing Group (.*)
>
> .* matches any character (except for line terminators)
>
> - Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>
> 2nd Capturing Group ([[0-9][0-9]?:[[0-9][0-9]?])
>
> [ matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)
>
> Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]
>
> 0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (ASCII 48) and 9 (ASCII 57) (case sensitive)
>
> Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]?
>
> ? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>
> 0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (ASCII 48) and 9 (ASCII 57) (case sensitive)
>
> : matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
>
> Match a single character present in the list below [[0-9]
>
> [ matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)
>
> 0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (ASCII 48) and 9 (ASCII 57) (case sensitive)
>
> Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]?
>
> ] matches the character ] literally (case sensitive)
>
> $ asserts position at the end of a line
>
> Global pattern flags
>
> g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
>
> m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)>

Comment: i guess this would be the last option i would love it to work without problem  rather than fix it each time

Answer (score 0):

Can just add a line break before the timecode?

```
if (evt.data.keyCode == 13) {
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertHtml('\n[' + tim + ']');
    evt.preventDefault(); // do not insert line break, because we already did this
}
```

But this adds timecode to the next line. If you want to add to current line, you can do something like

```
if (evt.data.keyCode == 13) {
    // get all current lines
    var lines = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.innerHtml.split('\n');
    // add timecode to beginning of last line
    lines[lines.length - 1] = '[' + tim + ']' + lines[lines.length - 1];
    // join all lines and write back to editor
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.innerHtml = lines.join('\n');
}
```

Comment: your solution seems correct but it didn't work, some thing not right with the ckeditor i guess when i see the source                                                                  '<p>my text [3.940068]</p>
<p>my new text [7.477115]</p>'